# get iotop to monitor a list of processes

Tags: bash, io

according to the man page  the -p switch should let you provide a list of processes to monitor

-p PID, --pid=PID
              A list of processes/threads to monitor (all by default).

i have tried  -p pid,pid2,pid3 
              -p pid pid2 pid3
              -p "pid,pid2,pid3"

and i always get the following error 
iotop: error: option -p: invalid integer value

can anyone show me the way to pass iotop a list of pid's to be monitored ?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iotop -p <pid1> -p <pid2> -p <pid3> -p <pid4>
```